# Why is the accepted range for unsigned int is from -128 to 127? Why not have the range from -127 to 128?

Tags: signed

For a signed 8-bit integer, why is the accepted range from -128 to 127? Why not have the range from -127 to 128?

Is it a **convention**?

Because the Math plays out and so does the bit-string pattern.

Comment: Because one bit marks whether the number is positive or negative, and 0 counts as positive.

Comment: Binary doesn’t normally support negative numbers, so people came up with a convention for it. It’s called “Two’s Complement”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement Essentially, you sacrifice the far left bit in order to have a sign. In an 8 bit number, this is the 128 slot. That means your positive numbers can only reach 127 — 01111111. -128 is represented as 10000000.

Comment: Mathematically it doesn't make sense to count 0 as positive, but in two's complement format, 0 is simply `00000000` - which means it has the same sign bit as the other positive numbers. Since equally half of the possible 256 values starts with `0` or `1`, if you use up one of the 128 `0` bit patterns for zero, then you only have 127 left-over `0` bit patterns for positive numbers (while you have the full 128 `1` bit pattens for the negative numbers). Making the range `-128` to `127` would basically mean assigning zero a pattern that starts with `1`, which is suboptimal, given its prominence.